# How to remove a byte from /dev/urandom output?

Tags: shell

I want to send `/dev/random` data to a serial port, without the value `0xFF` which is omitted.

How can I do this ?
Something like: `cat /dev/random | remove_byte "0xFF" > /dev/ttyUSB0` could be a good idea, but I don't know what to use for `remove_byte`.

Comment: (untested) `tr -d '\377' < /dev/urandom >/dev/ttyUSB0`?

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works fine.

```
cat /dev/random | tr -d '\xff' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. But `cat /dev/random | tr -d '\377' > /dev/ttyUSB0` works.